# Why does Zod make all my schema fields optional?

Tags: typescript, express, zod

I am using Zod inside my Express & TypeScript & Mongoose API project and when trying to validate my user input against the user schema it returns types conflicts:

```
  Argument of type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; password?: string; passwordConfirmation?: string; email?: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserInput'.
      Property 'email' is optional in type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; password?: string; passwordConfirmation?: string; email?: string; }' but required in type 'UserInput'
```

Here is the schema def:

```
export const createUserSchema = object({
  body: object({
    firstName: string({
      required_error: 'First name is required',
    }),
    lastName: string({
      required_error: 'Last name is required',
    }).nonempty(),
    password: string({
      required_error: 'Password is required',
    })
      .nonempty()
      .min(6, 'Password too short - should be 6 chars minimum'),

    passwordConfirmation: string({
      required_error: 'Confirm password is required',
    }),
    email: string({
      required_error: 'Email is required',
    })
      .email('Not a valid email')
      .nonempty(),
  }).refine((data) => data.password === data.passwordConfirmation, {
    message: 'Passwords do not match',
    path: ['passwordConfirmation'],
  }),
});

export type CreateUserInput = Omit<TypeOf<typeof createUserSchema>, 'body.passwordConfirmation'>;


export interface UserInput {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  password: string;
}
```

How to make these Zod schema fields all not optional as it is making it optional by default?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This might be caused by not using `strict: true` in TypeScript compiler options as referred to installation section in [README](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#installation) file.

Following basic tsconfig.json file would fix that:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we achieve this without strict mode? I mean... I'm working in quite a huge project that would require a lot of work to change that...

Comment: @caeus seems like "strictNullChecks": true instead of "strict": true is enough for non-optional fields.
While this probably still force you to migrate some of code I think it will be much easier

Comment: I had set `"strict": true` but then saw later down the config I had set `"strictNullChecks": false` which threw me for a loop. Setting both to `true` fixed this issue for me. Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: @Artokun, for anyone stumbling upon this at a later point. `"strict": true` expands into the following options (all set to true): `noImplicitAny noImplicitThis alwaysStrict strictBindCallApply strictNullChecks strictFunctionTypes strictPropertyInitialization`. So in your case, you could've just removed `strictNullChecks` and set just `strict` to true.

Comment: I am still getting this error even _with_ having `strict: true`: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/3293

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by @pr0gramist in the comments, the accepted answer should be to add this setting in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true   
    }
}
```

Depending on your default zod configuration, you may need to add this  in your schemas as well:

```
requiredField: z.string().min(1)
```

This method is less intrusive than a `"strict": true`, which adds more typescript constraints to your code base.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed since my project still needed to be `"strict": false`

Comment: `.nonempty()` is deprecated. Come out with something else now.

Answer (score 4):

The `.nonempty()` is deprecated. Just use `.min(1)` instead

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to create a basic version and then extend it with 'passwordConfirmation' and relative refinement.
Also is important to 'infer' from zod to typescript, to make available typescript linting.

```
import { object, string, z } from 'zod';

export const userSchema = object({
  firstName: string({
    required_error: 'First name is required',
  }),
  lastName: string({
    required_error: 'Last name is required',
  }).nonempty(),
  password: string({
    required_error: 'Password is required',
  })
    .nonempty()
    .min(6, 'Password too short - should be 6 chars minimum'),
  email: string({
    required_error: 'Email is required',
  })
    .email('Not a valid email')
    .nonempty(),
});
type userSchema = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;

export const createUserSchema = object({
  body: userSchema
    .extend({
      passwordConfirmation: string({
        required_error: 'Confirm password is required',
      }),
    })
    .refine((data) => data.password === data.passwordConfirmation, {
      message: 'Passwords do not match',
      path: ['passwordConfirmation'],
    }),
});
type createUserSchema = z.infer<typeof createUserSchema>;

const us: userSchema = {
  email: '',
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  password: '',
};

const cui: createUserSchema = {
  body: {
    email: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    password: '',
    passwordConfirmation: '',
  },
};
```